# php mail is getting cut off

Tags: php, email

I am sending a long HTML email via php's mail function on my localhost. It is consistently getting cut off and I can't figure out why.

Here's the code producing the cut off email:

```
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "<table rules=\"all\" style=\"border-color: #666;\" cellpadding=\"10\">";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>Application</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>Personal Information</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Name</td><td>{$fullname}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Gender</td><td>{$_POST['gender']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Address</td><td>{$home_address}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Phone</td><td>{$_POST['primary-phone']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Email</td><td>{$_POST['primary-email']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>School Info</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Address</td><td>{$school_address}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Phone</td><td>{$school_phone}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>Describe Yourself</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Marital Status</td><td>{$_POST['marital-status']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Spouse's Name</td><td>{$_POST['partner-name']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>College Degree?</td><td>{$_POST['college-degree']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Graduation Year</td><td>{$_POST['grad-year']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>College Name</td><td>{$_POST['college-name']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>College Major</td><td>{$_POST['major']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>Employment Info</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Employer Name</td><td>{$_POST['current-employer']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Date Employed</td><td>{$_POST['date-employed']}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Employer Address</td><td>{$employer_address}</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
//and on and on for another 40 lines
```

And here's the resulting email's code:

`<html><body><table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10"><tr><td colspan='2'>Application</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>Personal Information</td></tr><tr><td>Name</td><td>Blake</td></tr><tr><td>Gender</td><td>male</td></tr><tr><td>Address</td><td>My Street<br>Town, IN 12345</td></tr><tr><td>Phone</td><td>555-555-5555</td></tr><tr><td>Email</td><td>my.email@gmail.com</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>School Info</td></tr><tr><td>Address</td><td>my street<br>my town, IN 12345</td></tr><tr><td>Phone</td><td>555-555-5555</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>Describe Yourself</td></tr><tr><td>Marital Status</td><td>married</td></tr><tr><td>Spouse's Name</td><td>Emily</td></tr><tr><td>College Degree?</td><td>yes</td></tr><tr><td>Graduation Year</td><td>2008</td></tr><tr><td>College Name</td><td>Purdue</td></tr>`

As you can see (or maybe not depending on the formatting) the email is cut off after the college name even though there is plenty more information.

What's the problem?
$message too large?
local mail server sends too quickly? (I'm using Mercury that came installed with XAMPP)

Thanks

Comment: wow you sure do like concatenation. remove the first half, does it break at the same point, or a particular length?

Comment: check if it's not a length limit. e.g. move a few lines in the "cutoff" section upwards and see if maybe you get truncation in the middle of a line. and as a general stylistic type, don't use multi-line concatenation to generate a long string. at least use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc).

Comment: Multi-line concatenation should still work, although you don't need to reuse the variable just do `.` at the end of a line, don't use `;`, then continue with your quotes on the next line. Finish all the code with `;`. I should stress your code is looking like it should still work. Check your `mail()` method, it should include your `content-type`, like: `mail($email, 'Thank You for Contacting PHPglue', $msg, "From: PHPglue@PHPglue.com\r\ncontent-type: text/html");`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SMTP has a restriction on the length of lines, either 1024 or 2048 columns, I'm not sure. Put newlines (`\r\n`) periodically in your body. I suggest after each `</tr>`. This will have no effect on the way the table is rendered, but it should prevent the truncation.

Comment: doh, should of noticed that, so use to smart libraries that take care of such things. phpmailer, swiftmailer et al

Comment: @Barmar, that did the trick! Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Comment: Each SMTP servers has a different limit. The best solution is to use the [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function.

Comment: @pirios All servers are required to allow at least 1024, his table rows are not even close to that. I'm not sure about the advisability of using `wordwrap()` on HTML.

Comment: @Barmar It should :) `wordwrap()` is best for HTML content. Some are using the `chunk_split()`, but to me not work. `wordwrap()` to do it correctly and mail was fine. In my case...

Comment: I spent one day trying to debug why the email body got cut off. I tried to loop thru a list and print out in a table. I saw your comment and put a '\n' after each </tr> and it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mail() method, it should include your `content-type`, like:

```
mail($email, 'Thank You for Contacting PHPglue', $msg, "From: PHPglue@PHPglue.com\r\ncontent-type: text/html");
```