# PHP mail mysteriously cut short

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Whenever I try to send a PHP mail, it gets cut short. I have tested to change the content of the message and it is clear that it is related to a character limit.

I have looked for a cause of the problem, the closest was this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536839/1185126) that said I should add new lines `\r\n` which I have.

What in the world am I doing wrong?

Content of message:

```
$content .= '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>';

$content .= '<p>Welcome the latest update from our site!</p> '."\r\n\r\n";
$content .= 'We hope you enjoy this week\'s published articles: '."\r\n\r\n";
$content .= '<p style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">'. $category[0]->cat_name .': <a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a> <br><span style="font-weight:normal;"> '. get_the_excerpt() .'</span></p>'."\r\n\r\n";
$content .= '<p>Access all articles at: <a href="http://domain.com">http://domain.com</a></p> '."\r\n\r\n";
$content .= '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam at tincidunt lacus. Nulla non mi hendrerit, tincidunt eros id, rutrum nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel libero risus. Vivamus vestibulum consectetur sapien.</p> '."\r\n\r\n";
$content .= '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam at tincidunt lacus. Nulla non mi hendrerit, tincidunt eros id, rutrum nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel libero risus. Vivamus vestibulum consectetur sapien, eget blandit felis lobortis eu. Vivamus porttitor dui eget urna pellentesque</p>'."\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
$content .= '</body></html>';
```

Code to send out the email:

```
function mail( $recipient, $sender, $name, $subject, $message ) {

    $subject = stripslashes( $subject );
    $message = stripslashes( $message );

    $headers[] = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";

    return wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you use to actually send the email?

Comment: Maybe `wp_mail` truncates your message?

Comment: @putvande I've checked up wp_mail and it shouldn't truncate the message as far as I can tell. This is a Wordpress core function.

Comment: Well, you're sending an HTML email for starters. Instead you should be sending a `multipart/alternative` email with a plain-text part as well as your HTML part.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Can you please post an answer explaining this solution?

Comment: It's not a "solution", it's just a thing that you're doing wrong. It doesn't have anything to do with your message getting truncated, but when sending HTML email you *should* always have a corresponding plain-text version. Helps with spam filters too :p

Comment: where is it being cut short.. what is the last line ?

Comment: @Pogrindis It gets cut short somewhere in the "Lorem ipsum..." part

Comment: take a look into wordpress_mailer methods.. and if you're going to use html, use the `<br/>` instear of `\r\n` itts less likely to be escaped.

Comment: this worked for me so its likely your server settings. Are you using sendmail?

Answer (score 0):

You will add headers for html. Look function [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set 
 $headers  ='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

// Mail it 
mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
```

And remove \r\n\r\n

Comment: If you look at my question, you will see that I have already set the headers to "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"