# Long string line breaking for unknown reason in PHP

Tags: php

I am generating an email and I noticed some of my inline CSS styling was not showing correctly. Upon further investigation, it appears as if my output is getting line breaks randomly throughout the string. Here is the portion of PHP where the line breaks are occurring

```
<?php
$message .= '<ul style="list-style:none">';
foreach ($fileLinks as $key => $value)
{
  $message .= '<li><a style="font-family:sans-serif;background:#1F6FA9;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;" href="' . $value . '">Download ' . $fileNames[$key] . '</a></li>';
}
$message .= '</ul>';
?>
```

This all looks fine to me

An example of the output where the string is breaking and going to a new line messing up my inline css would be (I added line numbers to make it easier to read):

```
1. <ul style="list-style:none">
2.     <li><a style="font-family:sans-serif;background:#1F6FA9;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;margin-
3. bottom:10px;display:inline-block;" href="http://myserver.com/file-transfer/download.php?i=Li4vdXBsb2Fkcy8wNi0xMi0yMDE1L2JnLmpwZw==">Download bg.jpg</a></li>
4.     <li><a style="font-family:sans-serif;background:#1F6FA9;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;" href="http://myserver.com/file-transfer/download.php?i=Li4vdXBsb2Fkcy8wNi0xMi0yMDE1L3NsaWRlMS5qcGc=">Download slide1.jpg</a></li>
5.     <li><a style="font-family:sans-serif;background:#1F6FA9;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;" href="http://myserver.com/file-transfer/download.php?i=Li4vdXBsb2Fkcy8wNi0xMi0yMDE1L3NsaWRlMS5wZGY=">Download slide1.pdf</a></li>
6.     <li><a style="font-family:sans-serif;background:#1F6FA9;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;" href="http://myserver.com/file-transfer/download.php?i=Li4vdXBsb2Fkcy8wNi0xMi0yMDE1L3NsaWRlMi5qcGc=">Downlo
7. ad slide2.jpg</a></li>
8.     <li><a style="font-family:sans-serif;background:#1F6FA9;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;" href="http://myserver.com/file-transfer/download.php?i=Li4vdXBsb2Fkcy8wNi0xMi0yMDE1L3NsaWRlMi5wZGY=">Download slide2.pdf</a></li>
9.     <li><a style="font-family:sans-serif;background:#1F6FA9;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;" href="http://myserver.com/file-transfer/download.php?i=Li4vdXBsb2Fkcy8wNi0xMi0yMDE1L3NsaWRlMy5qcGc=">Download slide3.jpg</a></li>
10.    <li><a style="font-family:sans-serif;background:#1F6FA9;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:3px;margin-bottom:10px;display:inline-block;" href="http://myserver.com/file-transfer/download.php?i=Li4vdXBsb2Fkcy8wNi0xMi0yMDE1L3NsaWRlMy5wZGY=">Download slide3.pdf</a></li>
11. </ul>
```

I can't find any consistency on where the line breaks or why. Any ideas? It is breaking between lines 2-3 and 6-7.

Here are my headers and `send` in case you need to reference it

```
<?php
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: file-transfer@myserver.com <file-transfer@myserver.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $request->email . "\r\n";

$send = @mail('me@gmail.com', 'New Files from Secure File Transfer', $message, $headers);
?>
```

I have tried doing a preg_replace to remove any \n or \r

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but could you try to add spaces in the style attribute, for instance after each semi-colon? It think the fact that it's one long uninterrupted word might be the cause.

Comment: @GolezTrol just tried it and no luck. I am stumped on this!

Comment: @Ronnie When are the lines messed up? If you print them right after the foreach loop or if you receive the e-mail?

Comment: @Rizier123 they are line breaking in the email. This is the case in gmail and thunderbird. 2-3 and 6-7 is where it is line breaking for no good reason

Comment: @Ronnie But if you print it before you send the email everything is fine, right ?

Comment: @Rizier123 oh, sorry, yes it is all one long line with no line breaks. Could this have something to do with my headers?

Comment: I think I figured it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536690/php-mail-is-getting-cut-off I am adding a "\r\n" after each list item and it appears to be working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email has line hard and recommended limits on line length which are detailed in [IETF RFC 5322 on "Internet Message Format - IETF Tools"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). You can use email libraries like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) to make email handling easier.

> 2.1.1.  Line Length Limits

> There are two limits that this specification places on the number of
> characters in a line.  Each line of characters MUST be no more than
> 998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding
> the CRLF.

> The 998 character limit is due to limitations in many implementations
> that send, receive, or store IMF messages which simply cannot handle
> more than 998 characters on a line.  Receiving implementations would
> do well to handle an arbitrarily large number of characters in a line
> for robustness sake.  However, there are so many implementations that
> (in compliance with the transport requirements of [RFC5321]) do not
> accept messages containing more than 1000 characters including the CR
> and LF per line, it is important for implementations not to create
> such messages.

> The more conservative 78 character recommendation is to accommodate
> the many implementations of user interfaces that display these
> messages which may truncate, or disastrously wrap, the display of
> more than 78 characters per line, in spite of the fact that such
> implementations are non-conformant to the intent of this
> specification (and that of [RFC5321] if they actually cause
> information to be lost).  Again, even though this limitation is put
> on messages, it is incumbent upon implementations that display
> messages to handle an arbitrarily large number of characters in a
> line (certainly at least up to the 998 character limit) for the sake
> of robustness.

Comment: In othe words, it's not PHP - it's mail servers doing it.

Comment: gotcha, I believe that is about the same answer I pointed to in my comment. It was about line length limits. Thank you for describing. For anyone looking at this in the future, adding a "\r\n" within the body of the message will create the new line. If I was going to be doing a lot with email message via PHP, I would certainly use a library like the ones you listed above.